# MySQL order by priority of the day

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Hi I`m trying to order by prioty of the day.

I would like to order like this:

```
id|date                |priority
1 |2016-03-10 16:00:00 |1
2 |2016-03-10 08:00:00 |2
3 |2016-03-10 10:00:00 |3
4 |2016-03-11 10:00:00 |2
5 |2016-03-11 09:00:00 |3
6 |2016-03-11 11:00:00 |3
7 |2016-03-11 15:00:00 |3
```

I tried many things but with no success, so I'm here to ask some expert in MySQL.

Thank you!

Comment: can you give examples of what you tried that did not work ?

Comment: Idk now, but none worked, I just want to order by priority of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY DATE(date), priority
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I did many things and the way to do this was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY priority;

Comment: OK, But I think you not undertand my need, I would like to order by priority of the day not only by priority.